# MYSQL Update from Select Join

Tags: mysql, sql

Morning everyone,

I have wrote a SQL query to fetch all the data from database I want updated but can work out how i would put an update statement in here.

```
SELECT product_id, product_title, prodcat_category_id, category_active, product_active from products 
LEFT JOIN productcategories on products.product_id = productcategories.prodcat_product_id 
LEFT JOIN categories on productcategories.prodcat_category_id =  categories.category_id 
WHERE category_active = 0
```

[image]

I want to update all these results to have product_active 0, but I've never done an update statement inside of a select join.

Comment: Outer Joins in UPDATES are vanishingly rare (and a bit weird - unless "WHERE x IS NULL" appears somewhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below query

```
Update products set product_active = 0 where product_id IN 
(
SELECT product_id from products 
LEFT JOIN productcategories on products.product_id = productcategories.prodcat_product_id 
LEFT JOIN categories on productcategories.prodcat_category_id =  categories.category_id
WHERE category_active = 0
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of selecting using joins, update with the joins.

```
update products
LEFT JOIN productcategories on products.product_id = productcategories.prodcat_product_id 
LEFT JOIN categories on productcategories.prodcat_category_id =  categories.category_id 
set product_active = 0
WHERE category_active = 0
```